# ansible debug msg failed_when and changed_when

Tags: automation, ansible, yaml, devops

y code -

```
# Update apt cache reposoitary
        - name: Update apt cache
          command: apt-get update
          register: return

# Debug msg
        - debug:
            msg: '{{ return }}'
```

result.stdout_lines

```
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Hit:1 http://server/pub/mirrors/ubuntu bionic InRelease",
        "Get:2 http://server/pub/mirrors/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]",
        "Get:3 http://server/pub/mirrors/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]",
        "Hit:4 https://download.package.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt bionic InRelease",
        "Hit:5 https://archive.repo.package.com/apt/ubuntu/18.04/amd64/2018.3 bionic InRelease",
        "Get:6 http://server/pub/mirrors/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]",
        "Hit:7 http://apt.package123.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease",
        "Fetched 252 kB in 1s (222 kB/s)",
        "Reading package lists..."
```

I would like consider if any one line has 2 string "Err" & "package" that means it has failed to update apt cache from website -  https://download.package.com/

I was thinking of something like below:

```
      changed_when: >
        (("Get" in return.stdout_lines) and
        ("package" in ret.stdout_lines))    or
        (("Hit" in return.stdout_lines) and
        ("package" in ret.stdout_lines))

      failed_when: >
        ("Err" in return.stdout_lines) and
        ("package" in ret.stdout_lines)
```

Question here is does 2 strings looks for all of the lines or line by line ?
if so how to get this worked on line by line check.

Answer (score 0):

When APT fails to download the package, it will return an error. In that case, stdout isn't used anymore, but *stderr*. So you most likely need to change it to:

```yaml
# Update apt cache reposoitary
        - name: Update apt cache
          command: apt-get update
          ignore_errors: true
          register: return

# Debug msg
        - debug:
            msg: '{{ return }}'
          changed_when: >
            (("Get" in return.stderr_lines) and
            ("newrelic" in ret.stderr_lines))    or
            (("Hit" in return.stderr_lines) and
            ("newrelic" in ret.stdout_lines))
          failed_when: >
            ("Err" in return.stderr_lines) and
            ("newrelic" in ret.stderr_lines)
```

> Question here is does 2 strings looks for all of the lines or line by line ?

A: It looks for all the 'text' in the stderr_lines output of that task.

> If so how to get this worked on line by line check.

A: Your code looks sane.

Perhaps you want to test this specific use case yourself. What you could do is append the following to /etc/hosts on your target system: 127.0.0.1 download.newrelic.com

This way, APT looks on the target machine for the repository. Since it isn't there, the download will fail.

Also note that Ansible has [update cache built-in the APT module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-update_cache).

Comment: stderr is same out as stdout_lines but in a single line, what I'm looking for on "Hit:4 https://download.newrelic.com/" specific line where it has download.newrelic.com...if this fails I will consider my apt update has failed as I'm not worried if any other lines have failed or not.. I could have put "Hit:4 https://download.newrelic.com/" but there number 4 here in this case can be any other number for other servers in 1000s of servers. I just want filter out "Err:* https://download.newrelic.com/" as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go working code -

```
-----------------
# Update apt cache reposoitary
        - name: Update apt cache
          command: apt-get update
          register: return
          failed_when: return.stdout_lines is search("Hit:* https://download.package.com")
          changed_when: return.stdout_lines is search("Err:* https://download.package.com")     

# Debug msg
        - debug:
            msg: '{{ return }}'

-----------------
```